# Cannot get exclusive lock on rpm database in Unix

Tags: unix, rpm, aix

I was trying to install a python rpm on **AIX 6.1** and it was taking too long and so I had to close ther terminal.

Later when I tried to install the same rpm as root I am getting the problem as :

```
root:stud -> $ rpm -i -v python-2.6.7-1.aix5.1.ppc.rpm
cannot get exclusive lock on database
error: cannot open /opt/freeware/packages/packages.rpm
```

How can I correct this.

And on executing ps aux | egrep -i 'yum|rpm' I get:

```
root:stud-> $  ps aux | egrep -i 'yum|rpm'
root     2359514  0.0  0.0  240  252  pts/1 A    09:32:10  0:00 egrep -i yum|rp
```

Comment: Is `lsof /opt/freeware/packages/packages.rpm` show something?

Comment: Are you running this as root? The `$` sign indicates a normal user.

Comment: @dchirikov : I get lsof: WARNING: compiled for AIX version 5.1.0.0; this is 6.1.0.0.

Comment: @Khaled: Yes I'm running this as root.When I try id command I get uid=0(root)

Comment: Is this the only message you got?

Comment: yes, Every time i tried to install rpm i get : cannot get exclusive lock on database error: cannot open /opt/freeware/packages/packages.rpm

Comment: Is it possible to reboot LPAR and try again?

Comment: OK. you have installed wrong version of lsof. Does `fuser /opt/freeware/packages/packages.rpm` work?

Answer (score 2):

It simple means that there is some other process which is having the lock for rpm and not giving you the access. Check for any processes which might use rpm in your machine.

This command should probably help:

# ps aux | egrep -i 'yum|rpm'

If this command shows you some process (which it should), you should either wait for that process to exit and kill the process if it's not needed.

If it doesn't, try your command again, and it should work.

You can also check for the lock file also in the location `/var/lib/rpm`.

Simply go to that directory and check for the lock file. If it's there, which most probably is stale, as you killed the terminal earlier, simply remove the lock file.

If that also doesn't work, try rebuilding the RPM DB with this:

```
 # rpm  --rebuilddb
```

Comment: when I tried the command I got this result : `root     2359514  0.0  0.0  240  252  pts/1 A    09:32:10  0:00 egrep -i yum|rp` So should I be killing this process.How can I confirm this is rpm process.

Comment: I can't make anything out of this output here. Can you please edit the post and put it there or may be use something like pastebin and let me know

Comment: Also, to the person who voted -ve on my answer, I would really appreciate a feedback that why you did that ...  and if you can't give the feedback, please don't vote

Comment: I have updated the question and posted the result.

Comment: Hmmm .. doesn't look that there is any other process running on the machine which is using the lock. Let me see if I can think of something else

Comment: Updated my answer, you can give it a shot

Comment: But if i do ps -u root i get one process using rpm.Can that be one to be killed?

Comment: Naah. That's the same process what you ran to check any other process. I was automatically finished as soon as you saw the output.

Comment: I tried cheking the location `/var/lib/rpm` but there were no lock files.Then I tried `rpm  --rebuilddb` command and got the error as `cannot get shared lock on database`

Comment: Looks like you already got the answer in other forum :)

I was expecting the same, that you are not root as your prompt was "$", but didn't say that as you already specified that you are root :(